# Report multiple errors at the same time

Tags: java

((Not deleting so that it can be used for future reverence)) for anyone needing help with a string that prints out multiple errors using if statements. Don't forget to import Scanner and regex.Pattern. Edited to reduce clutter and remove my specifics used.

```
public static boolean checkPass(String s) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[bB]{2}[0-9]{4};
    return p.matcher(s).find();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String inputMessage = "Enter a code to validate: ";
    String userInput = " ";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println(inputMessage);
    userInput = input.nextLine(); 

    while (userInput.length() != 6 || !checkPass(userInput)) {

    if (userInput.charAt(0)!= 'b')
        System.out.println("First Character is not a b or a B");
    if (userInput.charAt(1)!= 'b')
        System.out.println("Second character is not a b or B");
    if (!Character.isDigit(userInput.charAt(2)))
        System.out.println("Third character is not digit");

        System.out.println("Code: " + userInput + " is not valid");
            userInput = input.nextLine();
    }



    System.out.println("code: " + userInput + " is valid");



}
```

}

Comment: What you did looks fine to me. Can you tell what exactly you mean by "hung up"?

Comment: PS : You won't be crucified for getting help in completing your homework. You would be crucified if you had asked someone else to do your homework while you binge watch netflix. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if (userInput.charAt(2) != 0-9)...` does not check for the character at position 2 of `userInput` being not in the range `0` thru `9`.  It checks the character for not being equal to -9.  `char`s are never negative, so any character---even letters and punctuation---will pass this test.

What you want is either:

```
if (userInput.charAt(2) < '0' || userInput.charAt(2) > '9') 
   ...
```

or

```
if (!Character.isDigit(userInput.charAt(2)))
    ...
```

Comment: changing everything to if statements seemed to get the other portion working enough for the sample codes needed for the class. thanks again for the help. I cant upvote becuase I do not have enough points yet. Thanks so much for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution.

1. Put the code that checks the input in a method.
2. Return a `List<String>` from the method.
3. Add a string to the list for each error.